# Drawing multiple overlapping circle on google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have been trying to draw multiple circles on google maps.An outer circle with huge radius to cover all the other circles and multiple circles inside this.When two of the smaller circles overlap I wish to remove the alpha from the intersecting portion.This the screen shot of I have created.[image: This is a screenshot of what i have created.]

Here is the code:

```
var bounds = null;
var google_maps = null;
initialize();

function drawCircle(point, radius, dir) { 
    var d2r = Math.PI / 180;   // degrees to radians 
    var r2d = 180 / Math.PI;   // radians to degrees 
    var earthsradius = 3963; // 3963 is the radius of the earth in miles
    var points = 32; 

    // find the raidus in lat/lon 
    var rlat = (radius / earthsradius) * r2d; 
    var rlng = rlat / Math.cos(point.lat() * d2r); 

    var extp = new Array(); 
    if (dir==1) {var start=0;var end=points+1} // one extra here makes sure we connect the
    else{var start=points+1;var end=0}
    for (var i=start; (dir==1 ? i < end : i > end); i=i+dir)  
    {
        var theta = Math.PI * (i / (points/2)); 
        ey = point.lng() + (rlng * Math.cos(theta)); // center a + radius x * cos(theta) 
        ex = point.lat() + (rlat * Math.sin(theta)); // center b + radius y * sin(theta) 
        extp.push(new google.maps.LatLng(ex, ey)); 
        bounds.extend(extp[extp.length-1]);
    }
    return extp;
}

function initialize()
{
    var map_options = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(17.385044,78.486671),
        zoom: 15,
        minZoom:9,
        zoomControlOptions: {
            style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL
        },
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    google_map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), map_options);
    google_map.setOptions({styles: $scope.opt.styles});

    bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    var myCircles = new google.maps.Polygon({
        paths: [drawCircle(new google.maps.LatLng(17.385044,78.486671), 100, 1),
            drawCircle(new google.maps.LatLng(17.385044,78.486671), 0.5, -1),
            drawCircle(new google.maps.LatLng(17.383044,78.486671), 0.5, -1)],
        strokeColor: "#bababa",
        strokeOpacity: 0.4,
        fillColor: "#bababa",
        fillOpacity: 0.35
    });
    myCircles.setMap(google_map);
}
```

The intersection portion of the two circles must also be transparent.Is there a possibility of doing this?I could not find anything on the internet.

Answer (score 2):

Check whether this [demo example link](http://jsfiddle.net/w9dbm1hv/) helps for you.

This helps to find you the draw a circle based on your input in radius.

```
function initialize() {

var gm = google.maps,
    start_point = new gm.LatLng(17.385044,78.486671),
    map = new gm.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
        mapTypeId: gm.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        zoom: 16,
        center: start_point
    }),
    marker = new gm.Marker({
        position: start_point,
        map: map,
         //Colors available (marker.png is red):
         //black, brown, green, grey, orange, purple, white & yellow
        icon: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/marker_green.png'
    });
var radius = 500;
var radi= radius/2;
var radi1= radius/4;
var circleOptions = {
        strokeColor: '#FFFF00',
        strokeOpacity: 0.8,
        strokeWeight: 2,
        fillColor: '#FFFF00',
        fillOpacity: 0.35,
        map: map,
        center: start_point,
        radius: radius
    };

  var circleOptions1 = {
        strokeColor: '#F00FF0',
        strokeOpacity: 0.8,
        strokeWeight: 2,
        fillColor: '#F00FF0',
        fillOpacity: 0.35,
        map: map,
        center: start_point,
        radius: radi
    };

  var circleOptions2 = {
        strokeColor: '#F00FF0',
        strokeOpacity: 0.8,
        strokeWeight: 2,
        fillColor: '#F00FF0',
        fillOpacity: 0.35,
        map: map,
        center: start_point,
        radius: radi1
    };
    // Add the circle to the map.
    var markerCircle = new google.maps.Circle(circleOptions);
    var markerCircle1 = new google.maps.Circle(circleOptions1);
      var markerCircle2 = new google.maps.Circle(circleOptions2);

}


google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```